# How to use runtime config in composable?

Tags: nuxtjs3

I want to do this

`composables/apiFetch.ts`

```js
import { $fetch } from 'ohmyfetch'

export const useApiFetch = $fetch.create({ baseURL: useRuntimeConfig().apiUrl })
```

And use it within Pinia so I don't repeat myself writing `$fetch.create` over and over again for every single API call.

`somewhere_in_pinia.ts`

```js
...TRIM...

actions: {
  async doSomething(payload: SomeNicePayload): Promise<void> {
    const response = await useApiFetch('/something', { method: 'POST', body: payload })
  }
}

...TRIM...
```

But Nuxt won't allow me

```bash
[nuxt] [request error] nuxt instance unavailable
  at useNuxtApp (/D:/XXXX/frontend/prms-fe/.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:472:13)
  at Module.useRuntimeConfig (/D:/XXXX/frontend/prms-fe/.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:480:10)  
  at $id_Yl353ZXbaH (/D:/XXXX/frontend/prms-fe/.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:38358:90)
  at async __instantiateModule__ (/D:/XXXX/frontend/prms-fe/.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:40864:3)
```

I have been looking for solution online, followed instruction from the [official discussion](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/3215) to no avail.

**EDIT**

I don't want to use Nitro, since my backend is already written on Laravel. I need to access the host without re-typing it all over the place so I thought I could use `.env` and `runtimeConfig`.

Comment: You're working with SSR?  Have You initiated the runtimeConfig inside nuxt.config ? 
https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/runtime-config/#exposing-runtime-config

and later on in the file ```somewhere_in_pinia.ts``` put ```js const config = useRuntimeConfig()``` and check config, look here https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/3215#discussioncomment-3088206

Comment: Just remember that variables in .env file should be prefixed with ```NUXT_```

Comment: @devzom yes, I did that on my `nuxt.config.js` file. Do I need to decouple it and pass the config as a parameter every time I want to call my pinia actions?

Comment: have you found any solution yet? I'm facing the same problem, when accessing ```useRunConfig``` and ```useNuxtApp```  inside composable folder I get ```server error 500```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to access Nuxt instance while it's not ready yet. To make it work, write your composable as a function :

```
import { $fetch } from 'ohmyfetch'

export const useApiFetch = (url, params) => {
  const instance = $fetch.create({ baseURL: useRuntimeConfig().apiUrl })
  return instance(url, params)
}
```

Comment: Geez.. I thought directly assigning it to a variable would be the same

Comment: what would we do without heros like you @serenity Just saved me a lot of time

Comment: The trade-off is that it creates a new instance on each call of `useApiFetch()`.